# Symfony2: How to retrieve the UserChecker in a controller?

Tags: authentication, symfony, symfony-2.1

The [**UserChecker**](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserChecker.html) in **Symfony2** is a necessary class for user authentication.

Let's suppose you need to authenticate a user just inside a controller, you should define a function like the following:

```
protected function authenticateUser(User $user) {                
   $user_checker = ...//Get here the user checker
    try {
        $user_checker->checkPostAuth($user);
    } catch (AccountStatusException $e) {
        return;
    }

    $providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('firewall_name');
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);   
}
```

Notice that the `UserChecker` is defined as a non-public service in Symfony2:

```
  <service id="security.user_checker" class="%security.user_checker.class%" public="false" />
```

How to get the `UserChecker` in a controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I couldn't get your question. Could you explain with example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "get" a private service by using an alias. See:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html

Comment: Yes, it is true! it suffices to add something like the following service in **config.yml**:
  services:
    default_user_checker: 
         alias: security.user_checker